# Add SDL to my path

Tags: sdl, homebrew, cc

I install SDL via brew on my mac but I can't include it!
Here is my too easy code:

```
#include <SDL.h>
int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

when I compile it with cc, CC could not find SDL.h
I found that brew install SDL in Cellar but cc did not check this folder
Could you help me?

Comment: Not familiar with mac, but could you try `#include <SDL/SDL.h>` ? Works for me on Linux.

Comment: I want to install package and that package throw this error so I cant edit that!

Answer (score 8):

I know this post has 9 months old but if someone, somewhere in the internet try to find out how to use SDL with mac, just follow this.

DL .dmg file on the SDL website (V2).

Put SDL2.framework in /Library/Frameworks

In your code :

```
#include <SDL.h>
```

and compile with those flags :

```
`sdl-config --cflags --libs`
```

Ex :

```
gcc test.c `sdl-config --cflags --libs`
```

---

Use this simple code to see it working :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[ ] )
{
    SDL_Surface *screen;
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) == -1 )
    {
        printf( "Can't init SDL:  %s\n", SDL_GetError( ) );
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    atexit( SDL_Quit ); 
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( 640, 480, 16, SDL_HWSURFACE );

    if( screen == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Can't set video mode: %s\n", SDL_GetError( ) );
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }   

    SDL_Delay( 3000 );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: When I downloaded it and put it into /Library/Frameworks, that worked. but it could not find the sdl-config program.

Comment: Nvm, I installed sdl2, so it needed to be `sdl2-config`

Comment: Neither sdl-config nor sdl2-config is found for me after installing the framework.  Where are these commands supposed to be?